How to turn a home battery on or off based on net voltage
sorry in advance for this probably trivial question. I'm not much familiar with EE yet.
My parents are running a farm in the Netherlands, but during milking in winter, the voltage gets so low that some devices start to fail. We suspect that this is due to the farm having a too small power cable running to the farm. Or maybe the region is the problem because my father has the feeling it mostly occurs when there is a high load in the nearby villages.
Luckily, the farm has solar panels which means there are no problems during the summer. However, during summer we have noticed that the panels shut down very often since the voltage gets above the maximum (253 V if I'm not mistaken).
So my question is: when we install a home battery of say 15 kWh, can we set this up to charge whenever the voltage gets above 245 and deliver if it gets below, say, 215? What kind of switch would we need for that, or how to set such a thing up? Is my mental model correct that in essence we can always dump power into the system or take it? So apart from the usual inverter, you can just have switches to turn the battery on or off?

While you in theory can trade electricity with the grid in and out, you are going to help your neighbors more than your own house. This also will get somewhat expensive in terms of battery degradation. If you are not on a flat rate, you may also end up buying electricity when it is expensive and trading it back when it is cheap. Not a deal, especially when the autotransformer is a more than a century old technology. In short, get a voltage regulator instead of a battery.

@fraxinus did you mean autotransformer?  These are fixed-ratio

@Frog variable ones do exist, but my personal experience in a rural area is that you only need ~10-15% fixed, to be used for up and down step. 10% down may be good for the day and 10% up for the night. 10% means a grid transformer w/24v secondary here in Europe.

p.s. ~100-300 eur investment together with a voltmeter and a manual 3-position switch

Thanks, I'll look into it. I think the battery degradation point is a bit outdated right? Assuming you ensure the system operates in a proper temperature range. Tesla's should run 750.000 km with only 20% degradation, according to Maarten Steinbuch, a Dutch professor a the Technical University of Eindhoven (https://maartensteinbuch.com/2024/02/18/onze-vijfde-tesla-en-vijf-tips-voor-nieuwe-tesla-rijders/).

@RikH no, it is not outdated. If you calculate the price of the electricity from the battery using the batery price and the expected cycle life, you will get numbers very bad compared to the grid price. In an EV car, this is the only electricity you have, but in a grid-powered house, this is a financial (and enviromental) nonsense.

That makes no sense. You know that we pay about €0,35/kWh in the Netherlands and battery costs have dropped about 10% per year? We're now at about 139$/kWh (https://about.bnef.com/blog/lithium-ion-battery-pack-prices-hit-record-low-of-139-kwh/). Tesla deployed 4 GWh in Q1 2024 alone and expect a 75% increase in 2024 compared to last year. Battery storage is being added to the grid at a rapid pace worldwide and even in the Netherlands. From my own calculation I would have earned the money back in 1 year, and I suspect the battery would last longer than that.

I'm considering reopening this question.


when we install a home battery of say 15 kWh, can we set this up to charge whenever the voltage gets above 245 and deliver if it gets below, say, 215?

If the grid voltage gets out of the allowed range, the inverter will shut down.
Within the voltage range allowed by the inverter, what you ask is possible, but there are simpler solutions.
How solar works with batteries:
A smartmeter measures power drawn by the whole installation (house, farm...). It reports this to the solar inverter.
The inverter will attempt to inject power into the grid to compensate for the power the house is using. If there is enough solar or battery available, the result is net power drawn from the grid is zero.
In this case your grid voltage will be whatever it is, it may drop due to high load in the neighboring village, but it will not drop due to the power you're using, because you're not using any net power. If the solar inverter compensates power used by the installation exactly, then no power flows in the wires between you and the grid, causing no voltage drop.
When batteries are full, and there is excess solar power available above what the installation consumes, then the inverter may inject that extra power into the grid, up to a maximum that you can set. This will cause your voltage to rise.
So, the usual "solar with batteries" hybrid inverter will help if your problem is the wires to the farm being too thin, but not if your problem is voltage dropping in the whole region.
You should talk to your grid operator about the voltage drops and ask if they can do something about it.
It is possible to know if your voltage drop problem comes from an inadequate power cable on your property, or to the utility transformer, or otherwise, by measuring voltage at various points. You can hire an electrician to do it, or organize a few people with cellphones and voltmeters.
--
How to do it:

Let's go to the point where voltage drop is the most problematic, like the farm next to the milking equipment. In a socket on the same circuit, you plug in a load that uses a lot of power, like a 2000W heater.
You need an accomplice to switch the load on/off, or a remote controlled socket, or a timer that switches it on and off say every two seconds.
Then you take a multimeter rated for measuring AC mains voltage and take measurements. It should be pretty accurate, because you'll need to measure 0.1V drops on 230V, so you may have to buy one.
You should ignore absolute value of mains voltage, as this will depend on other loads being switched randomly by everyone else in the vicinity. Instead the important measurement is the voltage difference between the moment the heater is on and when it is off. Ideally it should be repeated several times and give the same value of voltage difference every time, so you're sure it does come from your test heater load.
So you start at the socket where the heater is plugged, then walk further and further upstream, taking measurements at every opportunity: in the farm's electrical panel, the utility meter box, any point in between... then to a close neighbor's house, then a little bit further away.
Ohm's law is : V = R*I
Also P = V*I
Let's call "voltage difference between heater on and heater off" = Vd.
So if your heater draws 2kW then it's about 8.6 Amps. If the wire resistance is 1 ohm between the farm and the grid, that's Vd=8.6V.
Now if you find Vd=8.6V at the farm, and Vd=4V at the utility meter, then you have 4.6V between the two. Divide by the current, and that gives you the resistance between the utility meter and the farm.
Using this method you can estimate the resistance of your wires and find which one is the culprit.

Thanks for your explanation. I understand the inverter a bit better now. We talked to the grid operator and they have time in about 2 years, so that's why we're looking into alternatives.

Two years? damn! The key thing is a grid tied inverter does not set the voltage, the grid does. The inverter merely pushes power into the grid, at whatever voltage the grid gives. But it does influence voltage due to the injected current creating voltage drop in the wires. So it may solve your problem... or maybe not! I've edited the answer to explain how to measure the resistance of your wires simply so you can locate the problem yourself.

To get stable voltage you would either need an online UPS, which is expensive at high power, or an AC voltage regulator which is less expensive but has a limited voltage range. How much power is the problematic milking equipment using?
